# C++ Use of template class LinkedList requires template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, nodes

So when my Linked List class used only ints instead of the template T it worked perfectly, but when I went through and changed everything to be templatized, it gave me and error saying that "Use of template class LinkedList requires template arguments".

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class LinkedList
{
private:

    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        std::shared_ptr<Node> next;

        Node(T d, std::shared_ptr<Node> n)
        :data(d)
        ,next(n)
        {}
        Node()
        {};

        T getData()
        {
            return data;
        }

    };


    std::shared_ptr<Node> head;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> current;


public:


    LinkedList()
    :head()
    {}
    LinkedList(LinkedList& other)
    :head(Clone(other.head))
    {}

^This is where I think the problem is but did I just forget to replace an int somewhere?  I've looked this over a lot and I haven't found anything but I could just be blind.  

    std::shared_ptr<Node> getStart() const
    {
        return head;
    }

    //Insertion
    void InsertAt(T value, std::shared_ptr<Node> &n)
    {
        n = std::make_shared<Node>(value, n);

    }

    void Insertion(T value)
    {
        Insertion(value, head);
    }

    void Insertion(T value, std::shared_ptr<Node> &n)
    {
        if (!n)
        {
            InsertAt(value, n);
            return;
        }

        if (value > n->data)
            Insertion(value, n->next);
        else
            InsertAt(value, n);

    }

    //Deletion
    void Remove(T value)
    {
        Remove(value, head);
    }

    void Remove(T value, std::shared_ptr<Node>& n)
    {
        if (!n) return;
        if (n->data == value)
        {
            n = n->next;
            Remove(value, n);
        }
        else
        {
            Remove(value, n->next);
        }
    }



    void for_each(const std::shared_ptr<Node> &n)
    {
        if(!n) return;

        else
        {
            std::cout<<n->data<<std::endl;
            for_each(n->next);
        }

    }



    std::shared_ptr<Node> Clone(std::shared_ptr<Node> n) const
    {
        if(!n) return nullptr;
        return std::make_shared<Node>(n->data, Clone(n->next));
    }

    LinkedList& operator = (const LinkedList &list)
    {
        head = list.head;
        this->Clone(head);
        return *this;
    }



};



#endif
```

Comment: I have compiled your code without errors using `g++ -c -std=c++11 q.cpp` (g++ ver. 4.8.1)

Comment: Could you show the part of your code in which you use this class template(because i presume that is where your error occurs. Did you explicitly specify the type at the point of instantiation?)

Comment: The error means you didn't specify template argument while instantiating the template. In the code above there's no template instantiation.

Comment: please provide an example of `LinkedList` template instantation. The code above looks correct. Seems like you have forgotten to specify the type argumment during the instantation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also change the code where you use your `LinkedList`?

For example linked list of ints: `LinkedList<int> list;`